# How many different XML Namespaces are in this document?

Tags: xml, xsd, namespaces, xml-namespaces

Ok so I have this document:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <md:madcow xmlns:md="urn:Annotation"
               xsi:schemaLocation="urn:Annotation D:\projects\DELOS\Annotation.xsd"
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xmlns ="urn:Annotation"
               kind="withContent" media="text">
        <md:metadata>
            <md:author>ferro697702212</md:author>
            <md:title> Eine weitere Annotation </md:title>
            <md:creationDate>18/11/2009 10.26.09</md:creationDate>
            <md:modificationDate>18/11/2015 10.26.09</md:modificationDate>    

            <md:sourceHttp>687474703a2f2f7777772e676f6f676c652e69742f</md:sourceHttp>
                <md:type>example</md:type>
                <md:public>true</md:public>
        </md:metadata>
        <annotationBody xmlns="urn:Annotation">
            <contents id="1">
                <textContent>Das ist ein Beispieltext für eine Annotation</textContent>
                <attachments>
                   <attachedImage> file:://A/B/C</attachedImage>
                </attachments>
            </contents>

            <contents id="2">
                <md:textContent> Eine weitere Annotation </md:textContent>
                <attachments>
                    <attachedAudio>http://www.h_da.de/xml/test.mp3</attachedAudio>
                </attachments>
            </contents>

            <textSelection>
                <path>BODY/CENTER/FORM/TABLE[2]/TBODY/TR[2]/TD/FONT/LABEL[3],23,6</path>
                <contentRef>1</contentRef>
            </textSelection>
        </annotationBody>
    </md:madcow>
```

And here is my question:

How many different XML Namespaces are in this document?

As far as I can see it there is first:

```
xmlns:md="urn:Annotation"
```

which means this is the first one.

Then I have:

```
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
```

which is the second one.

Then we have:

```
xsi:schemaLocation="urn:Annotation D:\projects\DELOS\Annotation.xsd"
```

which tells us where the schema for the xsi namespace is defined.

Then we have:

```
xmlns="urn:Annotation"
```

which tells us what the default namespace is.

And last we have:

```
<annotationBody xmlns="urn:Annotation">
```

which tells us that here we overwrite the default namespace for this particular element. This is btw what confuses me most, because why the hell do we need the namespace declaration here since its the default namespace anyway?

So yeah...

Did I understand/read the code correctly and if not can you please tell my why and how many different namespaces are in this document?

Thanks to everybody in advance.

Comment: It isn't clear why `<annotationBody xmlns="urn:Annotation">` has redundant default namespace declaration, but yes, you understand this XML namespaces correctly AFAICS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two different namespaces in this document, which are `urn:Annotation` and `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance`.

The `urn:Annotation` is mentioned three times, and it is both the default namespace for the document and is also associated with the `md` namespace *prefix*. Namespace *prefixes* are arbitrary and only have meaning within the elements in which they're defined.

This means that each of the following three elements are in the *same* namespace and carry exactly the same information content:

```
<Element xmlns="urn:example"/>
<a:Element xmlns:a="urn:example"/>
<b:Element xmlns:b="urn:example"/>
```

In your particular document, there is a certain amount of *redundancy*, in that the default namespace didn't *need* to be re-assigned in the `annotationBody` element. Nor did we really *need* the `md` prefix.

This document carries exactly the same *information*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<madcow
           xsi:schemaLocation="urn:Annotation D:\projects\DELOS\Annotation.xsd"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xmlns ="urn:Annotation"
           kind="withContent" media="text">
    <metadata>
        <author>ferro697702212</author>
        <title> Eine weitere Annotation </title>
        <creationDate>18/11/2009 10.26.09</creationDate>
        <modificationDate>18/11/2015 10.26.09</modificationDate>    

        <sourceHttp>687474703a2f2f7777772e676f6f676c652e69742f</sourceHttp>
            <type>example</type>
            <public>true</public>
    </metadata>
    <annotationBody>
        <contents id="1">
            <textContent>Das ist ein Beispieltext für eine Annotation</textContent>
            <attachments>
               <attachedImage> file:://A/B/C</attachedImage>
            </attachments>
        </contents>

        <contents id="2">
            <md:textContent> Eine weitere Annotation </md:textContent>
            <attachments>
                <attachedAudio>http://www.h_da.de/xml/test.mp3</attachedAudio>
            </attachments>
        </contents>

        <textSelection>
            <path>BODY/CENTER/FORM/TABLE[2]/TBODY/TR[2]/TD/FONT/LABEL[3],23,6</path>
            <contentRef>1</contentRef>
        </textSelection>
    </annotationBody>
</madcow>
```

Answer (score 0):

> How many different XML Namespaces are in this document?

None.

As @Damien_The_Unbeliever correctly points out, two distinct namespace URIs appear in the document: `urn:Annotation` and `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance`. But these namespaces are not "in" the document, they are outside it. That's the whole point about namespaces, they aren't local to a document.

If I have counted correctly, the document contains 4 namespace declarations representing 3 distinct namespace bindings to 2 distinct namespaces.